# Right way to describe in title

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have few titles that I'm not sure which one of them to use. 
I will try to explain what will be in the chapter.

**First:**
In the chapter I'm making few simulations that in each one of them I'm displaying a graph with trajectory of a "target" and a trajectory of a "decoy".

Which of the following is describes correctly as a title:

```
1) Modeling Target And Decoy Trajectory
2) Modeling Target And Decoy Trajectories
3) Target and Decoy Trajectory Modeling
```

**Second:**
In the chapter I will make a simulation that will make a graph showing the trajectory of a car hitting a target.

Which of the following is describes correctly as a title:

```
1) Modeling Intercept
2) Modeling Interception
```

Comment: First: I'd choose (3).  Second: let's make something similar to (3): Interception modeling.

Comment: I agree with aparente001, the more so since I remember exactly that question with pretty-much exactly those choices from 40-some years ago